# Can not excute command line in magento 2.1 with xampp php 7.0.6 on window

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have installed magento 2.1.0 with latest xampp window 7.0.6. The strange thing is I can not run command line after successful installation magento 2.1. It happens due to wrong PHP_VERSION_ID (on commandline it shows : 50519) even I install xampp php 7.0.6.

Do you have any idea to fix it ? Thanks

**On web interface, it shows 70006, but on command-line interface it shows 50519**

[image: Wrong PHP_VERSION_ID]

[image: Right version on Web]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook up your xampp php with the command line:

you have to add to windows PATH environment variables:

`;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php;`

or 
you can open Start >> CMD as administrator and write

```
C:\xampp\php phpfile.php
```

then test it with `php -v`;

Comment: Thanks. My mistake is I have added the old xampp with PHP 5.5 before new xampp. I have removed it and it works. Thanks for pointing the right direction.